# Why is not possible to update property on partial view using razor pages and dotnet 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-6.0, razor-pages

Why can I not update `public List<string> Images` property when `OnGetAsync` method returns the data?

I am trying render the images on my `_Carousel` partial but `public List<string> Images` property is still an empty list.
I am coming from `ReactJs` and I am still figuring out how dotNet razor pages works.

Is there any similar functionality in razor pages as `useEffect` in Reactjs?

```cs
namespace WebUI.Pages.Home.Item
{
    public class ItemModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<string> Images { get; set; } = new();
        private readonly ILogger<ItemModel> _logger;
        // private item service ...
        public ItemModel(Logger<ItemModel> logger)
    {
      // Item service
      _logger = logger
    }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromQuery] int id)
        {
            var result = await _itemService.getItemById(id);
            foreach (var item in result.ItemImages)
            {
                Images.Add(item.Url);
                // **Note that I can log item.Url here and it arrives correctly**
            }
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

partial `_Carousel.cshtml`, `@Model.Images.Count()` is still 0 even though the Item has been fetched and I can see the log that it has 3 images.

```cs
@model WebUI.Pages.Home.Item.ItemModel
@if (@Model.Images.Count() > 0)
{
  <div>URLs: @Model.Images.Count()</div>
}

<div class="col-xl-6">
  <div id="panel-1" class="panel">
    <div class="panel-container show">
      <div class="panel-content">
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
          // render images from @Model.Images
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@section Scripts { }
```

I also added `Item.cshtml` where partial `_Carousel.cshtml` is being called to render images.

```cs
@page
@using WebUI.Pages.Home.Item
@model WebUI.Pages.Home.Item.ItemModel

<div class="row">
  @Html.Partial("_Carousel", Model)
  <div class="card-group card-group-scroll"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script src="~/lib/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = document.URL;
    var id = url.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
    var data = {};
    axios.get(`@Url.Page("/Home/Item")?Id=${id.toString()}`)
      .then((response) => {
        item = response.data;
        var listItem = `
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" onClick=navigateToItem(${item.Id})>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">${item.Name}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">${item.Description}</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>`;
        $('.card-group').append(listItem);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  });
</script>
}
```

What is the razor way of doing this? I should point out that I am new to razor pages.
Any suggestions is mostly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor Pages works quite different compared to reactJs. You don't need to use javascript for this. `OnGetAsync` should not return json. It should return the Page. Your code could look like this:

`Item.cshtml.cs`:

```cs
public class ItemModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<ItemModel> _logger;
    // private item service ...

    public ItemModel(Logger<ItemModel> logger)
    {
        // Item service
        _logger = logger
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
    {
        Item = await _itemService.getItemById(id);
        
        return Page();
    }
}
```

`Item.cshtml`:
(using the partial tag helper is better)

```
@page
@using WebUI.Pages.Home.Item
@model WebUI.Pages.Home.Item.ItemModel

@if (Model.Item != null)
{
  <div class="row">
    <partial name="_Carousel" model="@Model.Item.ItemImages" />
    <div class="card-group card-group-scroll">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">@Model.Item.Name</h5>
          <p class="card-text">@Model.Item.Description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

`_Carousel.cshtml`:

```
@model List<string>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
  <div>URLs: @Model.Count</div>
}

...
```

Comment: I get a `NullReferenceException` at `Item.cshtml` page at the line `<h5 class="card-title">@Model.Item.Name</h5>`

Comment: Updated the answer. Added a couple of null checks. There are a lot of other ways to handle the case where `Item` property is null.